# In Excel, limit the total number characters (like 1000) in a range of cells

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am looking to limit my workbook users to 1000 characters over a range of cells (Example: `A5:A30`). In other words limit the total characters in the range `A5:A30` to 1000 characters.

Comment: Are you counting whitespace as characters?

Comment: Whitespace is fine just text characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a user fills in a cell that sends the range over the 1000 character limit, it will call `Application.undo` which should just remove the last text that they added.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A5:A30")) Is Nothing Then

        Dim charCount As Long

        Dim arrValues As Variant
        arrValues = Range("A5:A30").Value2

        Dim i As Long
        Dim tempSplit As Variant
        Dim j As Long

        For i = LBound(arrValues) To UBound(arrValues)
            tempSplit = Split(arrValues(i, 1), " ")

            For j = LBound(tempSplit) To UBound(tempSplit)
                charCount = charCount + Len(tempSplit(j))
            Next j
        Next i

        If charCount > 1000 Then
            With Application
                .EnableEvents = False
                .Undo
                .EnableEvents = True
            End With

            MsgBox "Adding this exceeds the 1000 character limit"
        End If

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: @Tmacjoshua Well the catch is that it will only run if named `Worksheet_Change` because that's what the excel event checks for after updating. So it sounds like you need to open another question so that you can safely combine it with your previous operations

Comment: @Tmacjoshua what is the runtime error you are getting, what line is it happening on, and what are you trying to type in when it happens.